# how do i take inputs from various textboxes and store it in an array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have an array of textboxes and a submit button. what i want to do is take all the values of the textboxes and store it in an array and display it.
But there's some kind of syntax error. PLS help

```
<form name="f1" method="post">
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$res=mysql_query("select * from gdc");
$n=mysql_num_rows($res);
echo $n;
$res2=mysql_query("select * from service");
$n2=mysql_num_rows($res);
echo $n2;

echo "<table>";
   for($i=0;$i<$n2;$i++)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++)
      {
         echo "<td><input type='text' name='fte".$i.$j."'/></td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
   }
echo "</table>";
?>

<p><input type="submit" name="btn" value="OK"/></p>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
   for($m=0;$m<$n2;$m++)
   {
      for($k=0;$k<$n;$k++)
   {
   echo $_POST['fte'.$m.$k];
   $cars=array([$_POST['fte'.$m.$k]);
}

for($s=0;$s<$n2;$s++)
{
   for($t=0;$t<$n;$t++)
   {
      echo $cars[$s][$t];
   }
}

?>
</form>
```

Comment: `array([$_POST['fte'.$m.$k]);` there is an extra `[`. Does that fixes the issue

Comment: @lexmihaylov...thank u so much. the echo is working but now ders another notification tats coming
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\theslant\test.php on line 46

line 46 is this:
echo $cars[$s][$t];

CAN U HELP?

Comment: You are getting this notice because the some of the input indexes is not set, probably because you are getting the same number for $n and $n2. Try fixing this `$n2=mysql_num_rows($res);` to `$n2=mysql_num_rows($res2);`

Answer (score 0):

the final working code should look like this .

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
    for($m=0;$m<$n2;$m++)
    {
        for($k=0;$k<$n;$k++)
        {
            echo $_POST['fte'.$m.$k];
            $cars[$m][$k]=$_POST['fte'.$m.$k];
        }
    }

    for($s=0;$s<$n2;$s++)
    {
        for($t=0;$t<$n;$t++)
        {
            echo $cars[$s][$t];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks aton. i am very new to php and you guys really helped me out alot